# Use curl to upload files to SharePoint Online - 403 FORBIDDEN

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, linux, curl

I have to upload files from linux box to SharePoint Online. I have used following command:

```
curl -k -ntlm --user myusername:password --upload-file test.txt "https://url/test.txt" -v
```

But I get error:

> 403 FORBIDDEN.

However, `wget` command works perfectly to download files.

```
wget --cookies=on --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --user myusername --password mypassword "https://url/test.txt"
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: It seems that ntlm is not supported in SPO. How about this method: https://williamvanstrien.blogspot.com/2018/05/authenticate-from-curl-into-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below command:

```
curl --ntlm --user username:password --upload-file myfile.xls https://sharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/myfile.xls
```

Source:

[Need to upload files from Linux to Sharepoint](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a3cc7c51-8451-42d8-bd4a-c8bf0438c026/need-to-upload-files-from-linux-to-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

[Uploading file to MS sharepoint using CURL fails](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6569a0ae-04c4-4be7-b79c-4b89e15869ce/uploading-file-to-ms-sharepoint-using-curl-fails?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: this is exactly what I have used. But it seems it seems -ntlm is not supported.